# How to solve differential equation that contains an integral term

Tags: integration, integral-equations

I'm trying to find an analytical solution for the following differential equation that contains an integral term:

\begin{align}
    \frac{d{v}_p(t)}{dt} &= \alpha + \beta\frac{d{v}_f(t)}{dt} + \gamma\frac{d}{dt}\big({v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t)\big) + 
    \label{eq:force_eq} \\
    &+ \mu \big( {v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t) \big)^2 +  \nu \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\frac{d}{d\tau}({v}_p(\tau)-{v}_f(\tau))}{\sqrt{(t-\tau)}} d\tau
    \nonumber
\end{align}
Where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \mu$ and $\nu$ are constant and the funcions $v_f(t)$ and $dv_f(t)/dt$ are known $\big($you might assume $v_f(t) = v_{0} cos(\omega t)\big)$. I want to solve this equation for $v_p(t)$. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Two things: have you considered differentiating w.r.t. t to remove the integral, and convert it to a second order equation? Is it guaranteed that $\frac{d}{dt}[v_p-v_f]=0$? Otherwise, the integral does not make sense.

Comment: The derivative of the whole differential equation becomes:

\begin{align}
    \frac{d^2{v}_p(t)}{dt^2} &= \beta \frac{d^2{v}_f(t)}{dt^2} + \gamma \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\big[{v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t)\big] +  \\
    &+ 2 \mu \big[ {v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t) \big] \frac{d}{dt} \big[{v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t)\big] + \nu \frac{\frac{d}{d\tau}[{v}_p(\tau)-{v}_f(\tau)]}{(t-\tau)^{1/2}} \Big|_{\tau=t} - \frac{\nu}{2} \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\frac{d}{d\tau}[{v}_p(\tau)-{v}_f(\tau)]}{(t-\tau)^{3/2}} d\tau
    \nonumber
\end{align}

Assuming $\frac{d}{dt}[{v}_p(t)-{v}_f(t)]=0$, still integral shows up.

Comment: @GavinRidley, I don't understand why do I need to make that assumption to make the integral sensible.

Comment: It's because the integral would be infinite if not: an integrand that takes on 0/0 at one point can be integrable (like $\sin(x)/x$) but something of the form of a finite number divided by zero has no hope of being integrable.